# Max retry error when trying to access a web page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am running a selenium script in python and I keep getting the following error.

**Max retries exceeded with url:**

```
/session/0a30a3155a42b56a8c74aae5c8829d76/url 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff4bcecb4d0>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Can someone help me out here?

Now I am just overriding it with a try statement and put it to sleep
then access the page again

Comment: Maybe they have blocked your IP for the url?

Comment: Check your internet connection and make sure you can access the webpage

Comment: So running the browser headless seems to solving the problem.